# string concatenation with variables in Jenkins bat command

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a simple Jenkins function / procedure:

```
def StartContainer() {
    def SqlPort = BranchToPort[env.BRANCH_NAME]
    bat "docker run -e \"ACCEPT_EULA=Y\" -e \"SA_PASSWORD=P@ssword1\" --name SQLLinux${env.BRANCH_NAME} -d -i -p $SqlPort:1433 microsoft/mssql-server-linux"
}
```

BranchToPort does exactly what I want it to do, the problem I have is plugging the value it returns into the following call to bat, I've tried all sorts of things and this either results in language compile errors with the groovy script or the bat command ending immediately after the -p command. There is obviously something really simple I'm missing here.

Comment: Can you provide outputs of the errors you are seeing. The string concatenation there is fine (although you are mixing syntax styles, env.BRANCH_NAME is wrapped in curly braces where as SqlPort is not)

Comment: just try `echo` command instead of `bat` and add result into your question. also add the correct command you want to execute with `bat`.

Comment: If I use the same syntax for the SqlPort variable as env.BRANCH_NAME, when I perform the Jenkins build I get the following are error stack beginning with:

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: BranchToPort for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue is down to scoping the Groovy map is declared outside of the scope of the method that spins up the container, if I move the declaration of the map into the same method as the one that starts the container, it works.

Comment: so question is closed? did you answer yourself?

Comment: Yes, the question is closed.

Comment: @ChrisAdkin why not marking your answer as accepted?